# Using constexpr vs const vs inline constexpr

Tags: c++, inline, constexpr

I recently learnt about global variables and their uses and implications. I also learn that the downside of using constexpr in header files has two downsides.

1. If a value in the header file is changed, every file will need to be recompiled
2. It violates the ODR

My first question is using *inline* before constexpr solves the problem of the ODR rule because it will point all of the same inline functions to the same memory address

My second question is does the inline keyword help solve the first problem, or will the first problem still persist even after implementing inline.

If the problem still persist, in what occasions would we prefer to use the extern const method in another .cpp file against the inline constexpr in the header file method?

Comment: This might help https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/07/23/how-to-define-a-global-constant-in-cpp/